# Arduino nano BLE sense Serial port Suddenly stopped working

Tags: serial, arduino-nano-ble

Last week I got my new Arduino nanao ble sense. Today I was executing a code on it which reads every sensor data on it and print it on serial monitor. I changed some parameters in my code and upload my code, while the code was uploading I opened the serial monitor and code was fully uploaded. Suddenly i got an error on terminal saying cannot find upload port. After that my Arduino board was never detected by the system. I tried to $lsusb to check whether the device is mounted on usb port but it didn't show up.... I tried on different PC and even that not detected... Plzz let me know if my hardware is damaged in someway? OR is there a solution to this???

Answer (score 1):

All that has happened is that you don't have a sketch running. When you have a board with a native USB connection a sketch has to be running to make that USB connection *be* anything.

You corrupted your sketch, so it's not executing.

All you need to do is manually trigger the bootloader to install a new sketch. According to the "Getting started" page:

> NOTE: If the board does not enter the upload mode, please do a double press on the reset button before the upload process is initiated; the orange LED should slowly fade in and out to show that the board is waiting for the upload.

Comment: Reset? Power cycle?

Comment: @JRobert Looks like double-reset.

Comment: @Majenko How do I manually trigger the bootloader for Arduino nano BLE can't find any thing about on get started page or any other place. BTW thanks for Answering!!!

Comment: @TauhidKhan I told you how in my answer - copied and pasted from the getting started page here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/NANO33BLESense#upload-the-program - look under "Upload the program" in the block in italics.  Press the reset button twice.